# I'm trying to save and load choices and its giving me the same error over and over

Tags: c#, ioexception

I keep getting

> The process cannot access the file another process is using it

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
public void SaveCheckedChoices()
{
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataFile)) 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Autorun
            writer.WriteLine(sublimeAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(sublimePackagesAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(sharpDevelopAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(eclipseAutorun);

            writer.WriteLine(outlookAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(youtubeAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(githubAutorun);
            writer.WriteLine(trelloAutorun);

            File.SetAttributes(dataFile, FileAttributes.Hidden);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}

public void LoadCheckedChoices()
{
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataFile);
        // Autorun
        sublime.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        sublimePackages.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        sharpDevelop.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        eclipse.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());

        outlook.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        youtube.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        github.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());
        trello.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sr.ReadLine());

        sr.Close();
    }
```

I made sure the file was created and that the only thing that was running was SharpDevelop and it still gives me the error, could someone please tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Serializing a class of options is easier than doing line by line FileIO.... that is if Settings is somehow inadequate for the job

Comment: I want to save them so when i reload it it automatically shows up and im not really familiar with serializing

Comment: What a great opportunity to learn something new!  you even have the term to google.  However all that code does is what Settings will do for you...for free

Comment: I would love to learn this could you give me some suggestions and tips

Comment: Ok I used a binaryWriter and its still giving the error

Comment: You don't need to close the file.  The "using" will automatically close the file.  You are stuck in the loop because writer is null and you can't close the file.

Comment: There is a whole `Settings` device built into VB and c#.  It does what that code does.  Get thee to MSDN and look it up.  The first part of learning something is doing research, grasshopper.

Comment: Can you give me a link i have terrible luck googling things

Comment: "Learning" includes "learning how to google"! Try googling "c# app settings example" and you'll get what you're after.

Comment: yeah i got it, now im just trying to save stuff

Comment: If you need help finding MSDN, you need more help than we can ever give.

Comment: Ha ha i can find MSDN

Answer (score 0):

```
File.SetAttributes(dataFile, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Must be moved to after the `writer.Close();`. I believe it needs exclusive access to the file.
Also you can use `File.ReadAllLines` in the second function.

And the most important part of my answer. Never, ever, ever, ever, I must insist, NEVER hide a configuration file; EVER. It will come back to haunt you.

**EDIT:**
For proper serialization read [xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data) or the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) of [newtonsoft.json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: This did not help or fix the problem